# setTimeout on toggle in jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle, settimeout, fade

My menu displays an icon and some text when hovering over the menu items. Unfortunately, when hovering from the top to the bottom (and back), the fade animation makes all the images and text go crossfading into each other, which isn't looking nice.

I'm looking for a way to put a setTimeout on the toggle so the icons and the texts only appear when the user hovers over a menu item for more than 1 second. If the user hovers quickly over the menu items, the icons and the texts won't display.

This is the jQuery I have now:

```
$('.button').hover(function () {
 var id = $(this).attr('id').substr(4);
 $('.content').not('#photo' + id).fadeOut();
 $('.text').not('#info' + id).fadeOut();

 $('#photo' + id).fadeToggle();
 $('#info' + id).fadeToggle();
});


$('.button').mouseout(function () {
    $('.content').fadeOut();
    $('.text').fadeOut();
});
```

I've made a jsfiddle with a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/MaxdeMooij/9ozqgLwq/
There are some topics about setTimeout on slidetoggles, but I can't integrate those sollutions in my code. Can anyone help me? It'd be great.

Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another solution using timers.  This one keeps the fadeout in play.

```
var timerHandle = null;
$('.button').hover(function() {
    if (timerHandle != null) {
        clearTimeout(timerHandle);
        timerHandle = null;
    }
    timerHandle = setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id').substr(4);
        $('.content').not('#photo'+id).fadeOut();
        $('.text').not('#info'+id).fadeOut();

        $('#photo'+id).fadeToggle();
        $('#info'+id).fadeToggle();
    }, this), 500);
});

$('.button').mouseout(function(){
    $('.content').fadeOut();
    $('.text').fadeOut();
    if (timerHandle != null) {
        clearTimeout(timerHandle);
        timerHandle = null;
    }
});
```

A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ozqgLwq/2/) has been provided.

Comment: Little more complicated, but the effect looks nice! Thank you. :)

Comment: No problems Max.  If the answer has value, as always, feel free to give it a vote up.

Comment: I've tried to vote up, but I don't have the required 15 reputation points for it. But I think I'll use this code because of the smooth fade. I spent days trying to solve this problem, and it took you 5 minutes..

Comment: @MaxdeMooij Howdy Max.  No worries my friend.  Don't give how long it takes to get to an answer a second thought.  I'm old and grey these days and have been programming for decades.  EVERYONE has to start somewhere.  Now if you tell me that you yourself have been writing JavaScript for 20 years already ... well ... err ... :-)

Comment: Hahaha, that's true. Okay, you writing javascript even before I was born explains a lot. ;) Thanks again Kolban!

Answer (score 0):

Is this the effect you are looking for? Hide immediately on next `li` but fade out otherwise...

```
$('.button').hover(function () {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('.text').hide();
    var id = $(this).attr('id').substr(4);
    $('#photo' + id).fadeToggle();
    $('#info' + id).fadeToggle();
}, function () {
    $('.content').fadeOut();
    $('.text').fadeOut();
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/9ozqgLwq/1/)